# Cannot build packages from source using "apt source" and "debuild"

Tags: 18.04, apt, compiling, official-repositories, debuild

I have a strange problem. I want to build x264 and gpac from source on Ubuntu 18.04 using the official command "apt source", followed by "sudo apt get build-dep" then "debuild".

For x264, I got this error:

```
dh_install --list-missing --sourcedir=debian/install
dh_install: Please use dh_missing --list-missing/--fail-missing instead
dh_install: This feature will be removed in compat 12.
/home/try1/x264/ubuntu/x264-0.152.2854+gite9a5903/debian/x264.install: 1: /home/try1/x264/ubuntu/x264-0.152.2854+gite9a5903/debian/x264.install: shared/usr/bin/x264: not found
/home/try1/x264/ubuntu/x264-0.152.2854+gite9a5903/debian/x264.install: 2: /home/try1/x264/ubuntu/x264-0.152.2854+gite9a5903/debian/x264.install: shared/usr/bin/x264-10bit: not found
dh_install: debian/x264.install (executable config) returned exit code 127
debian/rules:77: recipe for target 'override_dh_install' failed
make[1]: *** [override_dh_install] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/try1/x264/ubuntu/x264-0.152.2854+gite9a5903'
debian/rules:16: recipe for target 'binary' failed
make: *** [binary] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary subprocess returned exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1152:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -us -uc -ui failed
```

For gpac I got that one:

```
ln -sf libgpac.so.4.5.0 /home/try1/gpac/gpac-0.5.2-426-gc5ad4e4+dfsg5/debian/tmp/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpac.so.4
ln -sf libgpac.so.4.5.0 /home/try1/gpac/gpac-0.5.2-426-gc5ad4e4+dfsg5/debian/tmp/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpac.so
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/try1/gpac/gpac-0.5.2-426-gc5ad4e4+dfsg5'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/try1/gpac/gpac-0.5.2-426-gc5ad4e4+dfsg5'
mv debian/tmp/usr/share/man/man1/mp4box.1 \
    debian/tmp/usr/share/man/man1/MP4Box.1
mv debian/tmp/usr/share/man/man1/mp4client.1 \
    debian/tmp/usr/share/man/man1/MP4Client.1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/try1/gpac/gpac-0.5.2-426-gc5ad4e4+dfsg5'
   dh_install -O--parallel
/home/try1/gpac/gpac-0.5.2-426-gc5ad4e4+dfsg5/debian/gpac.install: 1: /home/try1/gpac/gpac-0.5.2-426-gc5ad4e4+dfsg5/debian/gpac.install: usr/bin: not found
/home/try1/gpac/gpac-0.5.2-426-gc5ad4e4+dfsg5/debian/gpac.install: 2: /home/try1/gpac/gpac-0.5.2-426-gc5ad4e4+dfsg5/debian/gpac.install: usr/share/gpac/gpac.mp4: not found
/home/try1/gpac/gpac-0.5.2-426-gc5ad4e4+dfsg5/debian/gpac.install: 3: /home/try1/gpac/gpac-0.5.2-426-gc5ad4e4+dfsg5/debian/gpac.install: usr/share/man/man1: not found
dh_install: debian/gpac.install (executable config) returned exit code 127
debian/rules:17: recipe for target 'binary' failed
make: *** [binary] Error 127
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary subprocess returned exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1152:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -us -uc -ui failed
```

What is wrong?

Edit:
According to @Terrance reply, I have used these commands:

```
:$ sudo apt build-dep x264 gpac
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Then,

```
:$ apt source x264
:$ apt source gpac
```

Then, after download source is complete:

```
:$ cd x264-0.152.2854+gite9a5903/
:$ debuild
```

Also, the same for gpac:

```
:$ cd gpac-0.5.2-426-gc5ad4e4+dfsg5
:$ debuild
```

Comment: you mean `apt build-dep <package>` ?

Comment: What happened when you ran `sudo apt-get build-dep <package>`?

Comment: @bac0n YES. apt build-dep <package> for both **gpac** and **x264**

Comment: @Terrance This command is used for installing the build dependencies for <package> .

Comment: @hassan I know that is the command.  I was asking what happened when you ran it?  What is the output?  I had it not work when I was trying to build something because packages that are part of the `build-dep` were already installed.

Comment: Also, please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1274851/edit) your question and add in the exact commands you are running when building these.  We can see the errors fine, but without seeing what you are running we don't know if you are missing a switch command that might be needed.  You might be missing a sudo command.  We don't know.  Please help us help you with adding more details.  Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @Terrance for your help. The output for ```sudo apt build-dep x264 ``` and ```sudo apt build-dep gpac```  do not install any packages as all build dependencies are met.

Comment: @Terrance: the question had been edited.

Comment: I've tried building them, but I am not having much luck either.  They are failing over different errors.  I think there might be bugs in the way the source is.  Not sure though.  Normal installs of both apps through `sudo apt install <package>` are working fine.  Sorry I am not much more help here.  +1 to help with more exposure here.